# error after publishing app: The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address.

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, email, smtp

I am trying to create a program to send an email. my program works fine when I run it on local, but display an error after I publish it to the server.
this program trying to send an email inside gridview.
here is the gridview :

> checkbox ||   email1                   ||  email2
>       checkbox       ||   bla2.smptserver.com  ||     bla3.smptserver.com
>       checkbox       ||                        ||     bla3.smptserver.com

if email if email in column email1 is not null then the email will be send directly.

if email in column email1 is null then the email will be send to the recipient in column email2.

here is my code so far :

```
Private Sub sendEmail()
    Dim Username2 As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("username")
    Dim Password2 As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("1234")
    Dim Server2 As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("namesmtp.server.com")
    Dim X As Integer
    For X = 0 To GridView1.Rows.Count - 1
        Dim chkBox As CheckBox = CType(GridView1.Rows(X).Cells(18).Controls(1), CheckBox)
        If chkBox.Checked = True Then
            Dim email2 As String = ""
            Dim no As Integer = CInt(GridView1.Rows(X).Cells(0).Text)
            Dim id As String = Trim(GridView1.Rows(X).Cells(1).Text)
            Dim name As String = Trim(GridView1.Rows(X).Cells(2).Text)
            Dim item As String = Trim(GridView1.Rows(X).Cells(3).Text)
            Dim size As String = Trim(GridView1.Rows(X).Cells(4).Text)
            Dim qty As String = Trim(GridView1.Rows(X).Cells(5).Text)
            Dim clr As String = Trim(GridView1.Rows(X).Cells(6).Text)
            Dim type As String = Trim(GridView1.Rows(X).Cells(7).Text)
            Dim area As String = Trim(GridView1.Rows(X).Cells(8).Text)
            Dim ab As String = Trim(GridView1.Rows(X).Cells(9).Text)
            Dim reason As String = Trim(GridView1.Rows(X).Cells(10).Text)
            For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
                If row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
                    Dim chkRow As CheckBox = TryCast(row.Cells(18).FindControl("chkCtrl"), CheckBox)
                    If chkRow.Checked Then
                        Dim spv As String = Trim(row.Cells(16).Text)
                        Dim mgr As String = Trim(row.Cells(17).Text)
                        sql = "update tbl_name set [Attire App] = 'Approved', [Attire Date] = @ADate, [SPV App] = (case when [SPV id] = '' then 'Approved' else [SPV App] end) where No = '" & Convert.ToUInt32(no) & "' and [Badge ID]= '" + Convert.ToString(id) + "' and Uniform = '" + item + "' and [Attire App] is null"
                        Dim sqlcomm As New SqlCommand(sql, con)
                        sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ADate", Now.Date)
                        sqlcomm.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    End If
                End If
            Next
            If email2 <> "" Then
                email2 = Trim(GridView1.Rows(X).Cells(16).Text)
            Else
                email2 = Trim(GridView1.Rows(X).Cells(17).Text)
            End If
            Try

                Dim EmailMessage As System.Net.Mail.MailMessage = New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
                EmailMessage.From = New MailAddress("mail.address@something.com")
                EmailMessage.To.Add(email2)
                EmailMessage.Subject = "Attire Request"
                EmailMessage.IsBodyHtml = True
                Dim link As String = "Some link"
                EmailMessage.Body = "There is a request for attire from employee. Please approve the request by using the following link <a href=""" & link & """>Click here </a>"

                Dim smtp As New SmtpClient(Server2)
                Dim basicAuthenticationInfo As New System.Net.NetworkCredential(Username2, Password2)
                smtp.Credentials = basicAuthenticationInfo
                smtp.Send(EmailMessage)

            Catch ex As Exception
                lblError.Text = ex.Message
                lblError.Visible = True
            End Try
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

column email1 reside on gridview cell 16.
column email2 reside on gridview cell 17.

it's work fine but after I publish it, it's throws an errror.
the error display is 'The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address. '

Thanks in advance...

Comment: `email2` probably contains junk and is not a valid `To` email address. (It is about the only relevant part of the question, but the details of which are not shown.)

Comment: do you have any suggestion how to fix this problem?

Comment: First step is to look at the *full* exception message (eg. on which line was the error thrown or from which method did it propagate?) to see if my assertion above is correct. If it was thrown on `To.Add` (or `Send`), then what *is* the value of `email2` when the code is actually run?

Comment: I don't know how to see the error because it's work fine on the local, but error after published instead...

Comment: @user2864740 I think the content of gridview column that doesn't have an email inside is &nbsp; ....

Comment: @user2864740 I have Solved it... I only need to edit the config and added from = "fromemailadddress@something.com" inside the email setting...

Thanks for all the help..

Comment: Cool, glad the issue is resolved!